# How do I install ActiveAndroid for use with Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, activeandroid

I'm learning Android and Java at the same time, so sometimes I get hung up on the Java side of things.

I'm trying to use the ORM library ActiveAndroid, but the archive I downloaded doesn't contain a .jar file, just a libs folder and a src folder.  How do I import/install/incorporate this into my Eclipse Android project?

Comment: libs folder contain android.jar try to put that jar file in your project's libs folder

Comment: tried that. that is not the right .jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

- Compile the jar from source, add the library to the build path
- Or, Download a jar from here:
  https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/downloads

Following resources may help you

- https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/issues/5
- https://www.activeandroid.com/
- https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 1):

I built the jar by running `ant` in the ActiveAndroid root directory.  ActiveAndroid.jar is then located in the `dist` directory. (The build.xml file is an ant build script)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution worked for me (have only "plain" Eclipse, Indigo SR2):

1. File->New->Project...
2. Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile
3. Select build.xml